# Is there a way to search for ......?

Tags: feature-request, search

A few posts have shown up with crap added to them to extend the character limit past the point of acceptance. One user [liked to add periods](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/17750/revisions). I am having difficulties creating a query for `....`. Does anyone have a tip? If this ability does not exist, can it be added?

Comment: Can you use regular expressions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try a DataExplorer query such as [this one](http://data.stackexchange.com/english/q/98761/not-an-answer-candidates-upgraded), but note that it searches the most recent dump, not the live site.